# how to create a file with .dat extension in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: files

I am new to Ubuntu. I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 for the past few weeks. My question is, just like we can use notepad in Windows to create files with .dat extension, how do i create such a file in Ubuntu?
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is multitude of ways, as you can write text files with *any* extension you want.

With gedit text editor you can save the file as `testfile.dat`

Here's one way in command line: `echo "TEST" > testfile.dat`

Another way in command line to create multiple files with same content: `echo "TEST" | tee {one,two,three}.dat`

You can even rename an existing file to `.dat` file simply by using `mv sourcefile sourcefile.dat`